# How do I use tar to exclude all files of a certain directory?

Tags: tar

A client uploads files to a development server. When it's time to upload the project to a production server, those files are no longer needed, and we'd like to exclude them from the tar file we'll eventually push to production. However, we still want to keep the directory in tact, it's only the files that are not needed

Using Ubuntu 16 and tar 1.28, we've tried:

```
tar -vczf archive.tar.gz . --exclude=wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/*
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

We've also tried enclosing exclude= parameter in single and double quotations, no luck.

```
tar -vczf archive.tar.gz . --exclude='wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/*'
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

The [official website](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_49.html) shows --exclude without equals sign

`tar -vczf file.tar.gz --exclude 'directory/*' .` and gives the same error.

How is this done?

Comment: The 1st one is a wrong command. It is missing a target and the "." needs to go at the end. The 2nd one is wrong: it is missing a `=` after the exclude.

Comment: "that does not work either" - be specific: what happens?

Answer (score 32):

The usual gotcha with `tar`'s `--exclude` option is that it is *relative to the directory argument* e.g. given

```
$ tree dir
dir
└── subdir
    └── subsubdir
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        └── file3

2 directories, 3 files
```

then

```
$ tar cvf dir.tar.gz --exclude='/dir/subdir/subsubdir/*' dir
dir/
dir/subdir/
dir/subdir/subsubdir/
dir/subdir/subsubdir/file1
dir/subdir/subsubdir/file2
dir/subdir/subsubdir/file3
```

fails to exclude the contents of `subsubdir` (it's trying to exclude `dir/dir/subdir/subsubdir/*`, which doesn't match anything); what you want is

```
$ tar cvf dir.tar.gz --exclude='subdir/subsubdir/*' dir
dir/
dir/subdir/
dir/subdir/subsubdir/
```

AFAIK the order doesn't matter except that the output file must immediately follow the `f` option.

Comment: For me, this worked when I left off the quotation marks surrounding the excluded directory (`--exclude=subdir/subsubdir/*`)

Comment: Interesting.. for me, the answer didn't work, but the following worked. I left off the the quotes and made the exclusion paths relative to the working directory, not to the folder denoted by the dir argument... Working example for backing up the thunderbird-profile without the huge Mail and ImapMail folders `tar -vczf thunderbird-profile.tar.gz --exclude=.thunderbird/vph04o4g.default/{Mail,ImapMail} .thunderbird`

Comment: @ThomasPraxl in both yours and the previous commenter's cases, when you don't quote the pattern then you are relying on your current shell to do the expansion. The behavior you get will then depend on the shell's capabilities e.g. bash supports brace expansion whereas `tar`'s built-in globbing AFAIK doesn't.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for your explanation. Relying on the shell's capabilities sounds like the most reliable strategy to me. In any case: it is important to know, that you can do so. bash expands it to `--exclude=.thunderbird/vph04o4g.default/Mail --exclude=.thunderbird/vph04o4g.default/ImapMail`. Thus, you could also provide multiple `--exclude` arguments with hardcoded paths in the first place.

Comment: thanks, @steeldriver for the last AFAIK note. It saved me.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have a directory named "top-dir" with subfolders "dir/subdir". If you want to exclude content of a directory "dir/subdir" but not the directory itself, the command line that actually works is `tar -zcp --exclude='dir/subdir/*' -f archive.tgz top-dir`.

You have to use the `-f` switch after the `--exclude` one and before the archive file name.

Comment: so silly, took so long to figure this out on mac, exclude should go before -f

tar -zcv --exclude='.git' -f project.tar.gz project/

Comment: Nice info! Was wondering why my tar was trying to go into folders I thought I excluded... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Success Case:

1. If giving full path to take backup, in exclude also should be used full path.

   ```
   tar -zcvf /opt/ABC/BKP_27032020/backup_27032020.tar.gz \
   --exclude='/opt/ABC/csv/*' \
   --exclude='/opt/ABC/log/*' \
   /opt/ABC
   ```
2. If giving current path to take backup, in exclude also should be used current path only.

   ```
   tar -zcvf backup_27032020.tar.gz \
   --exclude='ABC/csv/*' \
   --exclude='ABC/log/*' \
   ABC
   ```

Failure Case:

1. If giving currentpath directory to take backup and full path to ignore,then it won't work

   ```
   tar -zcvf /opt/ABC/BKP_27032020/backup_27032020.tar.gz \
   --exclude='/opt/ABC/csv/*' \
   --exclude='/opt/ABC/log/*' \
   ABC
   ```

Note: mentioning exclude before/after backup directory is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put directories you don't want (for example `dir_A` and `dir_B`) in a file:

```
echo dir_A > FILE
echo dir_B >> FILE
tar -cvf file_name.tar --exclude-from=FILE directory/
```